# Adding a timer to a video recording or video in flutter

Tags: flutter, video, camera, flutter-dependencies

i'm trying to build an app in flutter where you can set a countdown timer and use the camera of the device to record videos with the timer on the screen (only the user can stop the video, the timer don't have to stop it), and i want that timer to appear on the video later when it's saved to memory. There is a way to do it? or a way of process the video and adding the timer? i have already done the code of the video recorder, the timer and the code that saves the video to the galery of the device. The dependencies i'm using are: camera, path_provider, path, video_player, gallery_saver, provider.

I have allready tried with ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full, but it didn't work.

This is my code where i tried to use FFmpegkit to add '00:00' but when i see the video in the device's gallery, it does not appear the text in the video.

```
// ignore_for_file: use_build_context_synchronously, avoid_print
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gallery_saver/gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
// import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full/ffmpeg_kit.dart';

class VideoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final XFile file;

  const VideoPage({super.key, required this.file});

  @override
  VideoPageState createState() => VideoPageState();
}

class VideoPageState extends State<VideoPage> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future _initVideoPlayer() async {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(widget.file.path));
    await _videoPlayerController.initialize();
    await _videoPlayerController.setLooping(true);
    await _videoPlayerController.play();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
   var nameDate = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
   String newName = "workout$nameDate";
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Preview', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 30),),
        titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white70,),
            onPressed: () async {
                print("path: ${widget.file.path}");
                try {
                  const savedDirectory = "/storage/Camera_Nacho_APP/";
                  final savedFile = '$savedDirectory/$newName.mp4';
                  final outputPath = '$savedDirectory/$newName(1).mp4';
                  final directory = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
                  final file = await File(widget.file.path).copy('${directory.path}/$newName.mp4');
                  await GallerySaver.saveVideo(file.path,albumName: savedDirectory);
                  await FFmpegKit.executeAsync("""
                      -i "$savedFile" 
                      -vf "drawtext=fontfile=fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf:text='00:00':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" 
                      -codec:a copy 
                      "$outputPath"
                  """);
                  await GallerySaver.saveVideo(file.path,albumName: outputPath);
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('El video se guardo correctamente'),));
              } catch (e) {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('El video el video no se puedo guardar, intentelo de nuevo.'),));
              }
            }
          )
        ],
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () { 
            Navigator.pop(context);
           },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined, color: Colors.white70,),

        ),
      ),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initVideoPlayer(),
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.